# Would tags for specific books be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'm wondering if tags for example Durret's Probability book would be allowed.

I think that when one is reading a book, it would be interesting what doubts other user had when reading the same book. It can improve our learning experience.

Comment: Rather not. I think that came up already, but I fail to find it.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is using subtags to identify book source appropriate for this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13817/is-using-subtags-to-identify-book-source-appropriate-for-this-site)

Comment: These past discussions are also related: [Is the tag \[hoffman-kunze\] necessary?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27658) and [Adding (hartshorne) Tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10056)

Comment: BTW it is still possible to mention in the text of the question where the problem comes from. So you can simply use [the built-in search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Durrett+Probability) or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Durrett+Probability+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com) for this purpose.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I don't think the built-in search works that well...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Well, all that creation of the tag does is that you have possibility to *search* using the given tag. In any case, if you wish to discuss this further we can [continue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2018/8/13) - so that we do not digress too much from the topic of the question (which was about creating the tag).

Comment: Math.SE could be seen to be endorsing the tagged books. Although this is not the intention, I believe it would be a by product of such tags. I do not think Math.SE should be seen to be endorsing books.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, there are a few similar past discussions<sup>1</sup> - you can see that having a tag for specific book is in general not a good idea.

One of the problems is that we would end up having too many very specific tags. (There are only five slots available for tags.) And it is better to use tag to describe what the question is about, tag for source of the question would be a [meta tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

On the other hand, I fully understand that you would consider useful to see whether there were some other questions from the book you're currently studying. There were also a few discussions related to this and some feature requests suggesting how this goal could be achieved more easily.<sup>2</sup>

Probably the best thing to do with the tools we already have in our disposal is to encourage askers to include the source of the question. This is already recommended in the FAQ: [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959#9960)

If askers include the information about the book, then you can use search to find questions you might be interested in. You can use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Durrett+Probability+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com) - this has the advantage that it searches in comments, too. (Searching in comments is [a bit more difficult](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12142/how-to-browse-or-search-comments).) Or you can use [the built-in search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Durrett+Probability+is:q). This only search posts, but you have the advantage that you can easily sort search results by votes or activity, filter them using tags or additional keywords, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup>See: [Is using subtags to identify book source appropriate for this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13817), [Is the tag [hoffman-kunze] necessary?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27658), [Adding (hartshorne) Tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10056), etc.

<sup>2</sup>See: [Categorizing homework questions with textbook information in a way that makes the site act like a solutions manual](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4218), [Centralized solutions to textbook problems considered harmful?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9142), etc.